# A riddle for your time (3)

Tags: riddle

This one is slightly harder then the previous two.

> I'm not a pool, a tree, a slave, a website, or a shirt.
>
> But all have something that is related to me.
>
> What am I?

Comment: I think there are many possible answers (anything other than pool, tree. slave. website and shirt can be the answer.

Comment: Yes, but probably only one relevant non-trivial answer... ;)

Comment: I have updated the question using your hint. Hope it is ok for you.

Comment: Like i said, this one is slightly harder ;) In this case i think the hint actually needed to be part of the question so its fine by me @AeJey

Comment: Well actually, i dont think this riddle can result in only one answer, although i have a specific answer in mind the answer to this riddle may actually be different then the one i anticipated at first.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think it's

> Book

**Explanation**

> Pool and book have cover 
>  Tree and book have leaves
>  Slaves and books are bound 
>  Website and book have pages 
>  Shirt and book have sleeves.

Comment: Haha right again ;) You sir are amazing at riddles.

Comment: Slaves and books are _bound_, not _bounded_.

Comment: `have` please, not `has`

Answer (score 7):

maybe you are

> a dog 
>  - a tree has a bark 
>  a slave has a master 
>  a shirt has a collar
>  a pool can have a guard (ie guarddog)
> ... though i'm struggling with website...

Comment: Nice try but not the right answer unfortunatly

Answer (score 6):

maybe you are

> Golf 
> website has links 
> tree has wood 
>  slave has irons 
>  shirt could be a tee-shirt
>  pool has water

Comment: Another good try although the reasoning on the pool is pretty far fetched ;)

Comment: thanks @Macro Geertsma - maybe the pool had a leak? - a hole-in-one! ;-)